# Given input dates as strings find Age in Days

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, formatting

I have a procedure that calculates age in days. I am thinking of using it to help me calculate *my pay days*. 
I want it to ask for date 1 and then date 2, which would also be the current date. 
However, I want it to be fancier and not even ask for date 2. 
I want to use `(time.strftime('%Y,%-m,%-d'))` for the input of the second set of dates when I run this code. 
I already have the code built for calculating my total net income from my 3 jobs.

```
y1,m1,d1 = 1994,4,1 #Birth_Date
y2,m2,d2 = 2014,1,1 #Current_Date
print daysBetweenDates(y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2)
```

My problem is that if I made `y2,m2,d2 = (time.strftime('%Y,%-m,%-d'))`
it will print it out with quotes at end so --> `'2014,2,3'` 
and then everything just falls apart. I have been looking everywhere to find the solution
and everyone keeps talking about the datetime stuff but my problem with that is that is returns

```
datetime.strptime('2014-12-04', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2014, 2, 3)
```

not only the date but also the `datetime.date`

I then tried

```
s = datetime.strptime('2014-12-04', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
s = string [16:-1] #
```

to remove all excess stuff but that didn't work also.

Please help me figure this one out guys. 
I want `y2,m2,d2 = current date` without quotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate age in day(days between date) with the following:

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('1975-10-03', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2014-12-05', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
day_between_dates = (end_date - start_date).days
>> 14307
```

Comment: I am going to upvote it and accept it as the answer because this is ultimately the best solution to this problem. This is easily reproducible and can later used at any time. My solution, though that it fits the constraints of the original problem, is not useful later on. I also know there a lot of other technical issues there too because datetime stuff is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

## Intro to Computer Science Problem: Age in Days

I should have informed everyone of the constraints of: **No Imports**

I apologize for that, it was my first question I ever posed and had no idea how to pose them correctly.

My solution below without any imports:

```
def isLeapYear(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:
        if year % 100 != 0:
            return True
        else:
            if year % 400 == 0:
                return True
    return False

def daysInMonth(year,month):
    if month == 1:
        return 31
    if month == 2:
        if isLeapYear(year) == True:
            return 29
        return 28
    if month == 3:
        return 31
    if month == 4:
        return 30
    if month == 5:
        return 31
    if month == 6:
        return 30
    if month == 7:
        return 31
    if month == 8:
        return 31
    if month == 9:
        return 30
    if month == 10:
        return 31
    if month == 11:
        return 30
    if month == 12:
        return 31


def nextDay(year, month, day):
    """Simple version: assume every month has 30 days"""

    if day < daysInMonth(year,month):
        return year, month, day + 1
    else:
        if month == 12:
            return year + 1, 1, 1
        else:
            return year, month + 1, 1

def dateIsAfter(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    """Returns True if year1-month1-day1 is after year2-month2-day2.  Otherwise, returns False."""
    if year1 > year2:
        return True
    if year1 == year2:
        if month1 > month2:
            return True
        if month1 == month2:
            return day1 > day2
    return False        

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    """Returns the number of days between year1/month1/day1
       and year2/month2/day2. Assumes inputs are valid dates
       in Gregorian calendar."""
    # program defensively! Add an assertion if the input is not valid!
    assert dateIsAfter(year2, month2, day2, year1, month1, day1)
    days = 0
    while dateIsAfter(year2, month2, day2, year1, month1, day1):
        days += 1
        (year1, month1, day1) = nextDay(year1, month1, day1)
    return (days) 

y1,m1,d1 = 1994,7,14 #Birth_Date
y2,m2,d2 = 2014,1,1 #Current_Date
print daysBetweenDates(y1,m1,d1,y2,m2,d2)
```

#### My answer: 1 Year & 7 Months later :).

I had solved it, but just forgot to post it as an answer in the community.
I am leaving this here if anyone else might find this useful to learn from.

P.S However, thank you @user3277225 for your answer. It is a very elegant and simple solution that I might use later when I need to.